# Convert java.util.List<String> into java.sql.Array

Tags: java, jdbc

How would you convert a `java.util.List<String>` instance into a `java.sql.Array`?

Answer (score 39):

Use [`connection.createArrayOf(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createArrayOf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[]%29)

For example:

```
final String[] data = yourList.toArray(new String[yourList.size()]);
final java.sql.Array sqlArray = connection.createArrayOf(typeName, data);
statement.setArray(position, sqlArray);
```

Where typeName is:

> the SQL name of the type the elements of the array map to. The typeName is a database-specific name which may be the name of a built-in type, a user-defined type or a standard SQL type supported by this database. This is the value returned by Array.getBaseTypeName

---

As noted in the comments, this is Java 1.6. For older versions you can't create this in a driver-independent way. You are only supposed to *get* arrays, not create them. If you want to, you can instantiate the implementing class from your jdbc driver, but this is non-portable.

Comment: which is the _current_ Java. If his is lower, he should've stated that.

Comment: yes you're right regarding the version of java, I just wrote my comment because I tried to look up the method in my bookmarked javadoc with is for 1.5 (as it is the version I have to use)...

Comment: It may be interesting to note that with an Oracle database, this method cannot be used. See the [documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/oraarr.htm#i1056647)

Comment: The proposed code causes an error  java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException, the answer is responded [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528337/passing-array-parameter-in-prepare-statement-getting-java-sql-sqlfeaturenotsu]

Answer (score 3):

The type argument to createArrayOf is the element type, not the array type, so you probably want something like "varchar" or "text".  VARIADIC is a function argument modifier, not a type specifier.