# Send ArraList<String> to SP Oracle

Tags: java, arrays, jdbc, arraylist

I have an **ArrayList** of Strings in my code Java, and I need to send this list to my **sp** in Oracle. I can´t set the list, because Array it's not compatible with ArrayList. How can I send this list?

```
public static boolean ejecutarPackageSeteado(String procedimiento,ArrayList<String> lista) throws Exception{            
    try{
        cs=getCallableStatement("{call "+procedimiento+"}");
        cs.setArray(1,lista);//THIS LINE SHOW ERROR         
        cs.execute();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }finally{
        cs.close();
        CallableStatementConnection.close();
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is my PrepareStatement

```
cs=getCallableStatement("{call "+procedimiento+"}");

//procedimiento is ="INSERTAR.INSERTAR_RUTFORZADA(?)"

private static CallableStatement getCallableStatement(String sql) throws Exception{
        if(CallableStatementConnection==null || CallableStatementConnection.isClosed()){
            CallableStatementConnection = getConnection();
        }
        return CallableStatementConnection.prepareCall(sql);
    }
```

Comment: but what is cs.????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert java.util.List<String> into java.sql.Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880304/convert-java-util-liststring-into-java-sql-array)

Comment: just do  `cs.setArray(1,lista.toArray(new String[0]));`

Comment: Which java version you are using?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ its a interface called CallableStatement that extends PreparedStatement

Comment: @Optional what yousay give this error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to Array".

Comment: @VishnuKR I think 7. If its relevant say me and I ask.

Comment: @LuisPavez I see it later. Do this `cs.setArray(1,CallableStatementConnection.createArrayOf(String, lista.toArray(new String[0]));` You may need to see if your connection variable is CallableStatementConnection or something different

Comment: @Optional show a error in this line "createArrayOf" it says in spanish "Función no soportada", in english its something like "unsupported function"

Comment: @LuisPavez See this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html#creating_array

Answer (score 2):

You need to adapt a little from `java.util.ArrayList` to `java.sql.Array`

```
Array sqlArray = connection.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", lista.toArray(new String[0]));
cs.setArray(1,sqlArray );
```

Comment: this does not recognize the word String : "String cannot be resolved to a variable".

Comment: @azro now the error is other,in this line "createArrayOf" it says in spanish "Función no soportada", in english its something like "unsupported function". What do you think about this

Comment: @LuisPavez what is your SQL statement ?